# Function having a non compact support

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

[image]

I've been reading in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#Compact_support) about compact support. I understood basically its definition "Functions with compact support on a topological space $X$ are those whose closed support is a compact subset of $X$.

But then when comparing this property with the condition of vanishing at infinity, I didn't understand why the function in the example has a non compact support.

I'm not a mathematician, so I need please a simple explanation. Thank you.

Comment: What is $\{x \in \Bbb R: f(x) \ne 0\}$ for your $f$ in the question?

Comment: If $x$ was equal for example to $1$, then $f(x=1)=0.5$ so here the output isn't zero

Comment: Solve for $x$ in $\frac{1}{1 + x^2} = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

The support of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$ (note that the support of a function is the subset of its domain on which it does not vanish), which is closed by definition, but $\mathbb{R}$ is not a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$. In other words, $f$ vanishes at infinity, but lacks compact support. To see that $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact, consider an open cover of $\mathbb{R}$:

\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}{(-n,n)}.
\end{equation*}

Because this open cover has no finite sub-cover, $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact (though this is perhaps beyond the scope of your question).

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ had compact support $K$, it would zero outside $K$. So, since $K$ would be bounded, there would be some $x_0 > 0$ for which $f(x_0)=0$, which does occur.